# Disable menu item in ContextMenu

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I use a context menu to modify the contents of a table show using a ListView.

I setup the menu in

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    ..
    MenuItem mi = menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_CONTEXT_EDIT_ID, Menu.NONE, MENU_CONTEXT_EDIT_TEXT);
    if (model.canBeEdited()) {
        mi.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else {
        mi.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

This makes the menu item grey but I can still click on it. How do I disable this completely - I want this to be shown, but the user should not be able to click on it.

I could just remove the menu item but I want the user to see that it cannot be edited.

Comment: Have you tried to invert setCheckable and setEnable ?

Comment: I don't think that calling setCheckable() makes sense. I'm not using checkmarks.

Comment: That's what you deleted it ok i've browsed the available method on MenuItem object and apart make your item invisible, I don't know how to do that

Comment: You can use a flag to prevent onClick not to function in the case of false